# Broken Menu Link Error

Tags: javascript, php, navigation

Just uploaded a script and everything seems to be good. But everytime I click any of the menu links in the header, I get this response:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /register was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Any tips, please? Here's my code:

```
<?php if($this->session->loggedin): ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('dash'); ?>">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('logout'); ?>">Logout</a></li>
    <?php else: <li><a href="<?= base_url(); ?>">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('about'); ?>">About</a></li>

    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('faq'); ?>">FAQs</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('support'); ?>">Contact Support</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul cl?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('login'); ?>">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('register'); ?>">Register</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: what is your link's href?

Comment: @Adeniran Please edit this into the question itself.

Comment: Okay. I'm new here, so. Thank you.

Comment: Please [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) & then ask again.